# Generating total number of n-lettered alphabet combinations in C

Tags: c, algorithm, logic

I am supposed to write a logic to generate a combination of n-lettered words.

For example, if the number 2 is provided, I am required to generate all two-lettered words from a-z i.e:

```
    aa-ba-ca.....za
    ab-bb-cb.....zb
    .
    .
    .
    .
    az-bz........zz
```

I understood that nested loops will not suffice for this problem since the number of nested loops changes with the number of letters in the word. This turns me to recursion, but I can't think of the logic.

Comment: Think about how you would implement this for n=1. Then think about how you would implement this for n=2, given the results for n=1. Then extend this to n in general.

Comment: Why is this tagged `language-agnostic` yet in the title you state `in C`?

Comment: @GuyCoder Title has `C` but the question was tagged as `Java`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursion is the key here. Here is an example written in Java:

```
public static void printCombos(int totalWords, String s) {
    if(totalWords-- <= 0) {
        System.out.print(s + " ");
        return;
    }
    for(char i = 'a'; i <= 'z'; i++)
        printCombos(totalWords, s + Character.toString(i));
    System.out.println();
}
```

Invoke it:

```
printCombos(2, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 26^2 combinations for two letters, 26^3 combinations for three letters and so on - 26^n combinations for n letters

So you can just make one loop for values 0..26^n-1 and build correspoding combinations for every loop counter value

Python-like pseudocode:

```
result = [""] * n
for i in range(26**n):
    t = i
    for k in range(n):
         digit = t % 26
         result[k] = letter[digit]   #"a" for 0, "b" for 1 etc
         t = t // 26 
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

The point of this lesson is to teach you recursion, which is much more valuable than pedantic cheek... but just to be a contrarian, you could totally do this with nested loops if you want.  You can do it with an *unnested* loop...

```c
void up_to_n_letters(int n)
{
   char word[n];
   int i = 0;

   for (char letter = 'a'; i < n; letter++) {
      word[i] = letter;
      printf("%s,\n", word);
      if (letter == 'z') {
         letter = 'a' - 1;
         i++;
      }
   }
}
```